# Existence of relationship or association link (PowerDesigner)

Tags: mysql, database, powerdesigner

Im doing a database model using PowerDesigner and Im having some alerts that Im not see how I can solve.

I have some tables that have relationship, but I have 4 tables that dont have any relationship.

And in tables that dont have relationship, I´m getting this alerts:

Category: Entity

Check: Existence of relationship or association link

Object: Entity 'Stats'

Location: `<Model>`

Do you know how can I solve this alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it is just a `Warning` (not an `Error`). It is usually strange to have an `Entity`, which is not related to anything else, neither source, nor consumer of data. But, of course, it can happen: e.g. for technical tables, like application options, shared counters...

To have a clearer view of your model check status, you can disable the check, by unselecting it in the `Options` in the `Check Model Parameters` dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I already disabled now, and Im not getting any warning. Thanks!